# position of div in css not changing after trying padding/margin

Tags: css

I'm having some issues with a joomla site I'm working on

It got fixed yesterday, but now the client wants to have a smaller slideshow and I'm back to square one with the same problem again.

http://dev.turnim.com/clients/dance/

Below the fullscreen slideshow comes the company logo, and above the logo I have some really weird space. I tried everything I could think of in eliminating or adjusting the space, but firebug wasn't any help at all

The slideshow has his own module position and the company logo, incl the teaser text too

Any help, how to fix this, will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your slider (`.tm-fullscreen`) is auto adjusting it's height to varying window heights and pushing the rest of the content down. According to theme.js:46:

```
fullscreenPos.css("height", win.height() - headerbar.height());
```

You can either disable that, or set in your CSS:

```
.tm-fullscreen { 
    max-height: 300px /* Or desired height */
}
```

To keep it from expanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was focussing on the div below, since firebug showed that part extended at the top. Now it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

`.tm-fullscreen` has a height inline applied with javascript somewhere (probably in the plugin for the slideshow).

Alain is correct, but if you want a pure (albeit hacky) CSS fix, you can do this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: ABCpx) {
    .tm-fullscreen {
        height: XYZpx !important;
    }
}
```